# App crashes when Bitmap is loaded from within a method

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to make a multiple choice quiz. I want to display a bitmap so that the user has to guess who it is. Thus, at one point, I need to display a bitmap. I want to display this bitmap from a function called `setQuestionView()` but the app crashes when I do this.

```
public void setQuestionView(List<String> list) {
    //Retourne d'un entier au hasard d'une liste
    intPlayer=getRandomIntPlayer(list);
    //Retourne le nom du joueur
    strPlayer=getNamePlayer(intPlayer,list);
    //Affiche le portrait du joueur en image
    strDrawable=getNameDrawable(strPlayer);
    res = getResId(strDrawable,R.drawable.class);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),res);
    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);   
}
```

So basically, the method get the name of a random person (a Sport Player from a list) that the user has to recognize, and it should display the image of this Player. But the line

```
img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

makes the app crash. When I remove this line from the method then call the method and write this line just after the method, it works. But I would like to make the display of the image inside the method.

Do you have any solution ?

Thank you.

Here are the errors from logcat:

```js
12-02 14:41:51.879 25024-25024/com.oc.rss.morphingapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
12-02 14:41:55.339 25024-25024/com.oc.rss.morphingapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.oc.rss.morphingapp, PID: 25024
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.oc.rss.morphingapp/com.oc.rss.morphingapp.GameActivityTest}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                            at com.oc.rss.morphingapp.GameActivityTest.setQuestionView(GameActivityTest.java:170)
                                                                            at com.oc.rss.morphingapp.GameActivityTest.onCreate(GameActivityTest.java:77)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT**

I add the code where I call the method SetQuestionView

```
public class GameActivityTest extends AppCompatActivity {

String[] PlayersA= {"Messi","Cristiano Ronaldo"};

//"Ronaldinho","Griezman","Neymar",Pogba","Suarez","Lewandowski","Benzema",
//          "Cristiano Ronaldo","Modric","Iniesta","Hazard","Diego Costa","Gerrard","Neuer",
//        "Lloris"};
List<String> listA = Arrays.asList( PlayersA );

private int score;
Button b_good;
String strPlayer;
String strDrawable;
Bitmap bitmap;
int intPlayer;
int res;
ImageView img;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);



    //Afficher le TopScore
    //getting preferences
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int TopScore = prefs.getInt("key", 0); //0 is the default value

    TextView highestScore= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.topScore);
    highestScore.setText("Top: "+ TopScore);


    ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Button opt_1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
    Button opt_2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
    Button opt_3=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonC);
    Button opt_4=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonD);
    Button[] arr = {opt_1, opt_2, opt_3, opt_4};



    //Afficher le score
    score=getIntent().getIntExtra("score",0);
    TextView currentScore= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentScore);
    currentScore.setText("Score "+ score);


    setQuestionView(listA);

    //.....
```

Comment: Could you post the logcat error message when it crashes?

Comment: it is done now.

Comment: `img` is not initialized. Initialize it with findViewById(<res_id>)

Comment: it is initialised before the onCreate:  
ImageView img;  and the findViewById is placed before the call on setQuestionView in the onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have the same variable name in two different scopes.

First you have

```
ImageView img;
```

That is a class-level field.

But when you are assigning the value you use

```
    ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

This creates a new variable that "shadows" the class-level field.

Thus in your `setQuestionView` method the class-level field is still null.

Just change the assignment line to

```
    img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

and you should be all set.